# Building Java Lemmatizer

Tags: java, regex, lemmatization

I am trying to build a tokenizer by using Java API (without the ones provided by Stanford, Apache OpenNLP).
I have been able to segregate the words by using regex and Java Pattern/Matcher:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+".
```

I now want to find the lemma of the word.
I don't want to use StanfordNLP due to its licensing issues.
What next?
I guess I do need a dictionary as a model to refer/compare to.
And ...?
Has anybody been there done that? Trying to build a word lemmatizer using Java? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the list of words and you want to know if two words are the same, like "run", "runs", "ran" and "running".
You can do a http request to a dictionary, for example to :

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/runs

In this case the page redirect to :

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/run?q=runs

Then you can program a http request and if it was redirect to other word, then their are the same.

In other case like:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/run

You can read :

*verb (runs, running; past ran /ran/; past participle run)*

Then you can create a parser to interpret the information of the page

In Java you can easily create http request with:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
```